# WindowsError using RotatingFileHandler and subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Running Windows 7 and Python 2.7.8, logging with RotatingFileHandler, and using subprocess.Popen make it impossible for RotatingFileHandler to rotate its files after the Popen. Given the code:

```
import subprocess
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

handler=RotatingFileHandler('log.txt', maxBytes=100, backupCount=10)
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info('before Popen')
s=subprocess.Popen('notepad')
logger.info('after Popen')
```

I get the error:

```
python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\prog64\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 77, in emit
self.doRollover()
  File "c:\prog64\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 142, in doRollover
    os.rename(self.baseFilename, dfn)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
Logged from file t.py, line 11
```

.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out that the file descriptor used for the log file was not closed before the call to Popen.

In the example above, execution of `notepad` does not depend on open file descriptors. These can be closed with the close_fds=True argument to Popen, coded as:

```
s=subprocess.Popen('notepad', close_fds=True)
```

Alternatively, when a sub process does depend on open file descriptors, but does not use the logger, it is sufficient to just close the logger file by calling:

```
handler.close()
```

just before the call to `subprocess.Popen`.